# How can I draw horizontal lines right and left from title

Tags: beamer, rules

I want a horizontal line right and left from the title. The line width should adjust to the title. So, for example, if the title takes 0.4\textwidth, the horizontal line left from the title, should take 0.3\textwidth, as the line right from the title.

So far, I have this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usebackgroundtemplate%
{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{/some/picture.png}%
}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}
\frame[c]{%
    \centering
    \Huge{\textbf{\rule{0.1\textwidth}{.4pt} Main title \rule{0.1\textwidth}{.4pt}\\
    subtitle}\\
    not bold text}
}
\end{document}
```

My problems are: 
1) The lines are not vertical in the center of the line, but at the bottom.
2) I have to adjust the width of the lines manually, so, if the title changes, the line-width has to be changed manually.

Can anyone help me out? Tried googling, but did not found, what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\leaders\hrule\hfill` to essentially perform an `\hrule` in horizontal mode.

I removed the background image from your example code and added a `\maintitle` macro that performs the formatting you want. I also added a small space on either side. I thought that looked better.
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\maintitle[1]{%
    \quitvmode
    \hb@xt@\linewidth{%
        \dimen@=1ex
        \advance\dimen@-2pt
        \leaders\hrule \@height1ex \@depth-\dimen@\hfill
        \enskip
        \textbf{#1}%
        \enskip
        \leaders\hrule \@height1ex \@depth-\dimen@\hfill
    }%
}
\makeatother

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}
\frame[c]{%
    \centering
    \Huge
    \maintitle{Main title}\\
    \textbf{subtitle}\\
    not bold text
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PERFECT, this is exactly, what I wanted! Thank you very much!